# What CSS position will best suit the following task

Tags: html, css, jinja2

I am making a template in jinja2(Its basic HTML and CSS). The template has Header, User info, Address and Account details, transactions. Most of the content is fixed so i have used position:absolute and defined its position on the page. The problem is with account and transactions. What css position property can I use to fix its starting point on the page but if it becomes long it does not overlap the bottom div ? The final purpose of this template is I want to print it in A4 sheet. So it looks like a report and the contents of these will be fetched from database.

Here is the code that I am experimenting with: I want the transactions box to move as the size of the account div is increasing.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
div.relative {
  position: relative;
  left: 40px;
  
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
   /* set a fixed height to prevent overlap with bottom div */
}
.container1 {
  position: relative;
   /* set a fixed height to prevent overlap with bottom div */
}
/* Then, position the account and transaction sections within the container like this: */

.account {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
   border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}

.transactions {
  position: absolute;
  
  width: 50%;
   border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="account">
  This div element has position: absolute;This div element has position: absolute;This div element has position: absolute;This div element has position: absolute;This div element has position: absolute;This div element has position: absolute;This div element has position: absolute;This div element has position: absolute;This div element has position: absolute;This div element has position: absolute;This div element has position: absolute;This div element has position: absolute;
  </div>
  
</div>

<div class="container1">
  <div class="transactions">
  This div element has position: absolute;
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```css
div.relative {
  position: relative;
  left: 40px;
  
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
   /* set a fixed height to prevent overlap with bottom div */
}
.container1 {
  position: relative;
   /* set a fixed height to prevent overlap with bottom div */
}
/* Then, position the account and transaction sections within the container like this: */

.account {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
   border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}

.transactions {
  position: absolute;
  
  width: 50%;
   border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="account">
  This div element has position: absolute;This div element has position: absolute;This div element has position: absolute;This div element has position: absolute;This div element has position: absolute;This div element has position: absolute;This div element has position: absolute;This div element has position: absolute;This div element has position: absolute;This div element has position: absolute;This div element has position: absolute;This div element has position: absolute;
  </div>
  
</div>

<div class="container1">
  <div class="transactions">
  This div element has position: absolute;
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you upload an image of your problem please? your codes too.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the starting point of the account and transaction sections on the page but prevent them from overlapping the bottom div, you can use the position: relative property.

First, define a container element for the account and transaction sections, and set its position to relative. Then, position the account and transaction sections within this container using position: absolute, but specify their positions relative to the container using the top, right, bottom, and left properties.

For example, you could define the container like this:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px; /* set a fixed height to prevent overlap with bottom div */
}

/* Then, position the account and transaction sections within the container like this: */

.account {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
}

.transactions {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
}

/* This will position the account section at the top left of the container, and the transaction section at the top right of the container, each taking up 50% of the width of the container. The height property of the container will prevent overlap with the bottom div if the content in the account and transaction sections becomes too long.

Remember to adjust the widths and positioning of the sections to fit your specific layout needs. */
```

Comment: Hey, I have updated the question. And tried to do what you suggested. Not working